# fine uploader add prefix to file name on s3

Tags: fine-uploader

So when I upload a file to s3, I want to retain the original file name, which appears to work if I use

objectProperties: { key:  "filename" },

I would also like to add a prefix to the object in S3.  So if I upload foo.jpg, I want the S3 object key to be '12345/foo.jpg'.  I'm going through the documentation and I'm not coming up with a clear direction to go in.

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 10):

To add a prefix to your object's keyname you can use the `objectProperties.key` option like so,

**non-jQuery Uploader**

```
var uploader;

uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    // ....
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (id) {
            return '12345/' + uploader.getName(id);
        }
    }
});
```

**jQuery Uploader**

```
$("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3({
    // ....
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) { 
           return '12345/' + $("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploader("getName",fileId); }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect.  This worked for me..
objectProperties: { key:  function (fileId) { return '12345/' + $("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploader("getName",fileId); } },

Comment: Had you tagged the question as `jquery`, Mark would have been able to use jQuery in his example and provide you with this exact code.

Comment: Updated to show examples with both uploader types. Please accept if it works!

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm.

I just want to add to anyone who was initially confused that the call to `uploader.getName(id)` or `$("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploader("getName",fileId)` returns the name of the file as you selected it on your filesystem. So if your selected a file to upload called: 'Black Dog.mp3' then the call to aformentioned functions gets you 'Black Dog.mp3'.

Answer (score 9):

To add to Mark's answer if you like that Fineuploader generated the UUID but you still wanted the file to be uploaded to a certain folder within the bucket you can just use the same approach but specify the method `getUuid`. Just make sure you extract the file extension from the original file name first like so:

**Non-jquery uploader**

```
uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    // ....
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) {

            var filename = uploader.getName(fileId);
            var uuid = uploader.getUuid(fileId);
            var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

            return  'folder/within/bucket/' + uuid + '.' + ext;

        }
    }
});
```

**jQuery Uploader**

```
$("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3({
    // ....
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) {

            var filename = $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploader('getName', fileId);
            var uuid = $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploader('getUuid', fileId);
            var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 

           return  'folder/within/bucket/' + uuid + '.' + ext;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
return prefix + '/' + $('#' + tagid).fineUploader("getName", fileId).replace(/[^\w\s.-]/gi, '');
```

in order to remove non-alphanumeric values.